# Style of drawing with small head and big body

Tags: style-identification, illustration

I often see pictures in web where people are drawn with small heads and big bodies. I think, Apple or JetBrains companies use this way of drawing.

Is it a specific style? How is it called?

[image]

Comment: I don't think the small-head/big-body is a style characteristic, but it is very similar to this  question: [What's the name of this cartoon style?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/8262/whats-the-name-of-this-cartoon-style)

Comment: I agree with Joachim.  I don't think that characteristic, alone, would be considered a separate style.  Flat illustration often uses some type of exaggeration, distortion, or humor to add interest to the minimalist representation.  These often mimic some of  the kinds of distortions a young child makes in drawing.